# (cross) validation of CNN models - when to bring in test data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cross-validation

For a research project, I am working on using a CNN for defect detection on images of weld beads, using a dataset containing about 500 images. To do so, I am currently testing different models (e.g. ResNet18-50), as well as data augmentation and transfer learning techniques.

After having experimented for a while, I am wondering which way of training/validation/testing is best suited to provide an **accurate measurement of performance** while at the same time keeping the **computational expensiveness** at a reasonable level, considering I want to test as many models etc.as possible.

I guess it would be reasonable performing some sort of **cross validation** (cv), especially since the dataset is so small. However, after conducting some research, I could not find a clear best way to apply this and it seems to me that different people follow different strategies an I am a little confused.

Could somebody maybe clarify:

*Do you use the validation set only to find the best performing epoch/weights while training and then directly test every model on the test set (and repeat this k times as a k-fold-cv)?*

*Or do you find the best performing model by comparing the average validation set accuracies of all models (with k-runs per model) and then check its accuracy on the testset? If so, which exact weigths do you load for testing or would one perform another cv for the best model to determine the final test accuracy?*

*Would it be an option to perform multiple consecutive training-validation-test runs for each model, while before each run shuffling the dataset and splitting it in “new” training-, validation- & testsets to determine an average test accuracy (like monte-carlo-cv, but maybe with less amount of runs)?*

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically, _do not make any decisions based on test set performance_!! That includes "choosing" a model based on that performance. Results on the test set should _only_ be used for reporting the final score, but any decisions leading up to that score have to be based on the validation set only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would remove 100 images for your test set. You should make sure that they resemble what you expect your final model to be able to handle. E.g. it should be objects which are not in the training or validation set, because you probably also want it to generalize to new weld beads. Then you can do something like 5 fold cross validation, where you randomly or intelligently sample 100 images as your validation set. Then you train your model on the remaining 300 and use the remaining 100 for validation purposes. Then you can use a confidence interval on the performance of the model. This confidence interval is what you use to tune your hyperparameters.

The test set is then useful to predict the performance on novel data, but you should !!!NEVER!!! use it to tune hyperparmeter.